# Multiple Pentaho Transformations 'Variables?'

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am using Pentaho Data Integration Software.

I am currently running a Pentaho Job as an ETL. I ETL data from multiple places and put them into a single database table. The schema for all of the places i ETL from are exactly the same. So, other than database connections and a single 'variable' that stores where that data came from, the transformation in Pentaho is exactly the same for each one. So i have a job, that runs each of these transformation.

The problem comes in, when i want to make a change. I need to change 6 transformations every time. What i want to do, is somehow set something like a variable in Pentaho, that tells it to run a single transformation, 6 times, with different database connections, and perhaps a single variable.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood your question correctly, you need to loop multiple transformations using a single KTR file *(assuming there is only one database **type**)*.

PDI provides you with a step called "Copy Rows to Result", where you can store the credentials of your database in multiple rows and for every run of the Job, it will use different connections and run the transformation multiple times (6 in ur case).

*Note: I have assumed that you are having only one database type e.g. : mySQL but with different credentials.*

Hope this helps :) I would be happy to provide you sample code in case you need it.

Comment: Yes, the databases i am connecting to are all mysql and exactly the same schema just a different host/user credentials. I'll give this a try and let you know. If you do have some sample code that would be helpful, as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you use a job that will pass the host/user/password as variables? That way your whole data flow will be generic.

Hope this answer will lead you into the right direction!