# How to Dynamically render Table name and File name in pentaho DI

Tags: file, dynamic, pentaho

I have a requirement in which one source is a table and one source is a file. I need to join these both on a column. The problem is that I can do this for one table with one transformation but I need to do it for multiple set of files and tables to load into another set of specific files as target using the same transformation.

Breaking down my requirement more specifically :

```
Source Table                     Source File    Target File

VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_0    VoiceRevenue0   ProfileVoice0
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_1    VoiceRevenue1   ProfileVoice1
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_2    VoiceRevenue2   ProfileVoice2
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_3    VoiceRevenue3   ProfileVoice3
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_4    VoiceRevenue4   ProfileVoice4
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_5    VoiceRevenue5   ProfileVoice5
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_6    VoiceRevenue6   ProfileVoice6
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_7    VoiceRevenue7   ProfileVoice7
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_8    VoiceRevenue8   ProfileVoice8
VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_9    VoiceRevenue9   ProfileVoice9
```

The table and file names are always corresponding i.e. VOICE_INCR_REVENUE_PROFILE_0 should always join with VoiceRevenue0 and the result should be stored in ProfileVoice0. There should be no mismatches in this case. I tried setting the variables with table names and file names, but it only takes on value at a time.

All table names and file names are constant. Is there any other way to get around this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "Copy rows to result" step. It will store all the incoming rows (in your case the table and file names) into a memory. And for every row, it will try to execute your transformation. In this way, you can read multiple filenames at one go.

Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792909/multiple-pentaho-transformations-variables/26796056#26796056) link. Its not the exact answer, but similar.

---

I have created a sample [here](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/tree/master/stackoverflow-pentaho-samples/DynamicallyRenderin). Please check if this is what is required.

In the first transformation, i read the tablenames and filenames and loaded it in the memory. After that i have used the get variable step to read all the files and table names to generate the output. *[Note: I have not used table input as source anywhere, instead used TablesNames. You can replace the same with the table input data.]*

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rishu for your input but with "Copy rows to result" step I can use both file names and table names as input and execute for each row,which in fact runs exactly as you said for file names too but how do I get this to read the table names in the table input step and execute for each row?

Comment: Have you tried using the Variables used in the "Copy rows to result" in the table input step??.. I mean use the variable to replace the table name in the TableInput Step.

Comment: Variables don't take multiple table values at a time, so copy rows to result should be bringing only one value other wise the set variable fails,

Comment: @DeviPrasad Please check the answer above. I have attached a sample code. i assume this is what you are looking for. !!

Comment: Yes this works fine. Thanks Rishu for your help. I cant give a thumbs up because my reputation is still low. But this is the right answer. Only thing is that I have to store the table names as I do it with the files. Rightly done Rishu..

Comment: Welcome :) yes u have to or you can use the database data-dictionary to get the list of tables ... And you can accept the answer if it is correct :)